# If E is an empty set, then P(E)=0. Is converse true? Why...?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Someone says that the statement "For event $E$, if $E$ is an empty set, then $P(E)=0$".
But I cannot find the reason why the converse of it is false?
Please give me some help!

Comment: Perhaps it's the converse: If $P(E)=0$, then $E$ can be nonempty (on an infinite sample space).

Comment: @egreg Even on a finite sample space :)

Comment: @egreg  Excuseme sir, do you mean that the original statement is true but its converse is false?

Comment: @Sophia Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland Well, if on a finite sample space an elementary event has probability zero… `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

It is always true that
$$E = \emptyset \Rightarrow P(E) = 0.$$

Conversely,

$$P(E) = 0 \not\Rightarrow E = \emptyset.$$

Indeed, suppose that there exists an elementary event $\{x\}$, such that $$P(\{x\}) =0.$$

Then, consider the set $E = \{x\}$. Of course, $E$ is not empty, but $P(E) = 0$.

Comment: One cannot use both notations $P(x)$ and $P(\{x\})$ in the same context (at present the latter makes sense but not the former). Please modify accordingly.

Comment: @Did thanks for your timeliness and accuracy!

Comment: Again some confusion: $x$ and $\{x\}$ are not both events, in your context only $\{x\}$ is. Which is why I tried to correct your answer -- but to no avail since you reverted it to the faulty version...

Comment: @Did thanks again for fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

$E=\emptyset\implies P(E)=0$ but the converse is not always true.

Take a counterexample: For a continuous random variable $x\in \mathbb R$ ( like the height of students in a classroom having probability density function $f(x)$), the probability of $a\leq x\leq b$ is $P(a\leq x\leq b)=\int_a^b f(x)dx$, then you surely have $P(x=l)=0$.